# Problemas con js externo en codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Estoy empezando a desarrollar con codeigniter. Dentro del view escribi un  y funciona a la perfección. Luego, decido cortar y pegar el script a una archivo externo para después incluirlo en el view y me da error en una de las funciones.

Este es mi script:

```
    <body>
    <script>function actualiza_carga(info, columna, id) 
    { $.ajax({ url : "<?php echo   site_url('index.php/book/book_update/')?>", 
     type: "POST", dataType: "JSON", 
     data:{ "id": id, "columna": columna, "info": info }, 
     success: function() { alert("Correcto"); }, 
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
     { alert("Se ha producido un error"); } 
     }); 
      }
     </script>
     </body>
```

Si coloco este código en el mismo php, el resultado es "true". Si copio y pego en un archivo externo y lo incluyo el resultado es "false".

```
    <body>.... 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>custom/carga.js" ></script> 
    </body></html>
```

¿Alguna pista para solucionar el problema? Se agradece

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: tu pregunta esta incompleta, ¿que error te da? ¿qué código es?

Comment: Ahí la edité. Gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Podrias mostrar como tienes definido tu base_url() ?

Comment: En la configuración aparece: $ config['base_url'] = ''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es crear una variable en el index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">base_url = '<?= base_url();?>'</script>
```

y en el arhivo javascript externo usar esa variable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#spe_id").change(function(){
    $.get(base_url + "user/ajax_getCity","spe_id="+$("#spe_id").val(), function(data){
      $("#city_id").html(data);
    });
  });
```